# replace the word in which there is a symbol

Tags: r, replace

I have the data

```
vec <- c("RT_12_ SDB", "ZT_12_", "_12TR", "RE_12_TR")
```

I want to replace all the data that has "_12" on "12"

what I want to get:

```
vec <- c(12 SDB,12,12,12)
```

I tried

```
vec <- gsub("\\b_12_\\w+", "12", c("RT_12_", "ZT_12_", "_12TR", "RE_12_TR"))
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just extract 12 from the data ?

```
as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(vec, '12'))
#[1] 12 12 12 12
```

In base R,

```
as.numeric(sub('.*(12).*', '\\1', vec))
```

---

For the updated data we can use -

```
sub("(?<=12)[A-Z]+", "", gsub('.*(?=12)|_', '', vec, perl = TRUE),perl = TRUE)
#[1] "12 SDB" "12"     "12"     "12"
```

where the inner `gsub` removes everything until 12 and the underscore whereas the outer `sub` drops the characters after 12.

Comment: I forgot to provide another option, with a space. Can you tell me ? Added to the question

Comment: How do you extract `12 SDB` from the 1st value but not `12 TR` from the last one ?

Comment: No, just for the space

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning here but this gives the expect output. `gsub("(?<=12)[A-Z]+", "", gsub('.*(?=12)|_', '', vec, perl = TRUE),perl = TRUE)` . Is this what you want ?

Comment: Yes, thanks. You can formalize this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
gsub('.*(12(_\\sSDB)?).*', '\\1', vec)
# [1] "12_ SDB" "12"      "12"      "12"
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `trimws` from `base R`

```
as.numeric( trimws(vec, whitespace = "\\D+"))
#[1] 12 12 12 12
```